# Finding the maximum elements (consecutive) whose sum is less than a given value?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

So, I have an array of all positive natural numbers. I am given a threshold value. I have to find out, the maximum count of numbers (consecutive) whose sum is less than the given threshold value.

```
For example, 
IP: arr = {3,1,2,1}
Threshold = 5

O/P: 3
```

Maximum size of input array can be 10^5.

Basically, I thought of an algorithm which calculates the count of elements in the subsets of the original array whose sum will be less than the given threshold. But, it will lead to a complexity of O(N^2). Can anyone suggest a better algorithm? I am not looking for a code and only a algorithm/pseudocode will do just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [maximum no. of elements in an array having sum less than or equal to k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37633701/maximum-no-of-elements-in-an-array-having-sum-less-than-or-equal-to-k)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int maximumSum(int[] array, int t){
    int maxSum = 0;
    int curSum = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    while(start < array.length){

        if(curSum > maxSum && curSum <= t){
            maxSum = curSum;
        }
        if(curSum <= t && end < array.length){
            curSum += array[end];
            end += 1;

        }
        else{
            curSum -= array[start];
            start+= 1;
        }
    }
    return maxSum;
}
```

The complexity of this code is O(2 * n) which is essentially O(n). I can't think of any improvement to this.

Comment: This solution isn't correct. It finds the max of sum of elements that <=t instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a bit rough, but should point you to an O(n) solution

Traverse the list with two pointers, both starting from the start, we'll call one the lead, and the other the trail, since one leads and one trails.

keep track of the sum from trail up to lead; and the length of the currently encountered longest valid sequence.

While the current sum is smaller than (or equal to) the threshold, advance the lead pointer and adjust the sum by adding the value it now points at. If the sum is still less than (or equal to) the threshold value, then the sequence from trail to lead is a possible one.

While the current sum is larger than the threshold, advance the trail pointer.

Continue until the lead pointer reaches the end.

You'll need to fill in the details and implement it carefully, but it seems sound enough to me.

Comment: I implemented what you said and I have edited my original post to include the code. However, in case the threshold is extremely big (an 8 digits number) and the number of element in the array is, `100000`, then it still gives a time limit exceeded. Can you tell me how can I optimise my code further?

Comment: Don't repeat the calculation of the sum. Exploit the fact that that the sum from Ai to Aj is equal to the sum from Ai to Aj-1 + A[j]

Answer (score 1):

I would try the follow:

- Start by summing elements from the beginning of the array, until you reach the threshold. Save this subarray as the temporary result.
- Then remove one element from the beginning of the subarray, and try to add new elements from the other side, until reaching the threshold again. If the result is bigger, replace the following result with the new one.
- Continue until end of array.

Comment: This sounds exactly like my solution which we posted at nearly identical times. That gives me some more confidence about them.

Answer (score 0):

Try below...

```
public int maximumElem(int[] array,int threshold)
{
   int sum = 0;
   for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
   {
     sum = sum + array[i]; //sum the values at each index
     if(sum >= threshold)  //check condition
       return (i+1); // if sum is reaching the threshold then return the index
   }
}
```

Hope this helps you...

Please let me know if you have any further questions...

Comment: But it won't return the maximum count. For example, if the input array would have been `6 1 2 3` and `threshold = 5`, your code will return `1` when it should return `2`.

Comment: for 6 1 2 3 and threshold 5, maximum count is 6 right?...how would it be 7