# maximum no. of elements in an array having sum less than or equal to k

Tags: arrays, sum, max

I want to find the maximum no. of elements in a given positive integer array such that their sum is less than or equal to a given no. k. For example, I have an array

```
[3,4,7,2,6,5,1] and k=6;
```

The Answer is 3 as 1,2,3 are maximum elements to give sum 6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sort the array, count the number of elements, then start summing elements sequentially until their sum is greater than k or you have gone through each element, then subtract 1 from the count if the sum is greater than k

Pseudocode:

```
    let k=6
    sort the array
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    let sum=0
    let count=7 //(7 elements in the array)
    for (i=0;i<7;i++) {
        sum+=array[i];
        if (sum>k)
            break;
    }
    if (sum>k)
    i--;
```

`i` is the max number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

A more 'Swifty' way might be:

```
var maxSum = 6
var newSum = 0

let maxElements = [3,4,7,2,6,5,1].sort().filter() {
       if $0 + newSum <= maxSum {
          newSum += $0
          return true
       }
       return false
    } .count    //returns 3
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. It might be the reason that it is written in the language other than Java C or I might now know these things. Can you elaborate your answer

Comment: Sorry.  I thought this was a Swift Language question.  I realize now it was not.  `Filter()` is a higher order function in Swift allowing you to do things like this with 1 line of code and very performant.  Sorry if I confused anyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
int maxIceCream(vector<int>& costs, int coins) {
        sort(costs.begin(), costs.end());
        int ret = 0;
        for (auto p : costs) if (coins >= p) {
            coins -= p;
            ret++;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: #Sample costs=[10,2,10,10,10,10,8,2,7,8]
coins=25
Answer= 4